# How can I set all the properties of an array of objects to true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I have some JSON data that I am attempting to map over and set all the properties to true.

I am aware that you can use the map function for this, however the way that the JSON is set up, each of the objects in the array has a key name.

So when I run the map function, it's setting all of the key names to false rather than the properties inside of the object itself.

Here is the JSON Data:

```
{
    "Presentations": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 5
    },
    "Articles": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 1
    },
    "Blogs": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 61
    },
    "NewsBriefs": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 2
    },
    "SpecialInsights": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 50
    }
}
```

Here is the map function I attempted, where `data` refers to the JSON above:

```
Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
     return value === true;
});
```

This in turn returns an array of five items with the value `false`:

```
[false,false,false,false,false]
```

What I am attempting to do is flip the values of any items that is false to true.

Comment: @silencedogood I dont think so, result would be same in that case too

Comment: I seriously don't understand what you trying to acheive? can you explain bit more to get answer.

Comment: `const truthify = o => Object.keys(o).forEach(k => { if (o[k] === false) o[k] = true; if (typeof o[k] === "object") truthify(o[k]); });` though note that without further checks, this would e.g. also affect properties that hold arrays, which hold true/false values. It's pretty much search and 
d̵e̵s̵t̵r̵o̵y̵ set true

Comment: @silencedogood hi, sorry if it wasn't explained clearly. What I am trying to do is change all of the values inside of each of the objects in the array to a value of false. So for example, all of the properties that are currently false under the "Presentations" object would be changed to values of true. And that would be the case for the other objects as well. 

The issue I'm having is I don't know how to reach down to the "second" level so to speak, currently my code is just change the key names to false rather than the properties of each of the objects themselves.

Comment: You do not have an array here. You have an object with objects inside it. That's a very important distinction, as arrays have different properties and methods than objects do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this using nested forEach as well, like this -

```js
    const a = {
      "Presentations": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 5
    },
    "Articles": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 1
    },
    "Blogs": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 61
    },
    "NewsBriefs": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 2
    },
    "SpecialInsights": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 50
    }
}
    
    Object.keys(a).forEach(ele => {
     Object.keys(a[ele]).forEach(childEle => {a[ele][childEle] = true});
    })
    
    console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to map anything

```
var arr = your_json;
for(a in arr){
    arr[a]['Instant'] = true;
    arr[a]['Daily'] = true;
    arr[a]['WeeklySummary'] = true;
}
```

and if you dont know the properties

```
for(a in arr){
    for(e in arr[a]){
        !arr[a][e] ? arr[a][e] = true : null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use recursion:

```js
function flip(o) {
  for (k of Object.keys(o)) {
    if (typeof o[k] === "object") {
      flip(o[k])
    }
    if (o[k] === false) {
      o[k] = true;
    }
  }
}



const o = {
    "Presentations": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 5
    },
    "Articles": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 1
    },
    "Blogs": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 61
    },
    "NewsBriefs": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 2
    },
    "SpecialInsights": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 50
    }
}

flip(o);
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of different ways of doing it depending on your ES version and browser support required.

```js
var data = {
    "Presentations": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 5
    },
    "Articles": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 1
    },
    "Blogs": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 61
    },
    "NewsBriefs": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 2
    },
    "SpecialInsights": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 50
    }
};

/* ES5 */
var outterKeys = Object.keys(data);
for(var o = 0; o < outterKeys.length; o++){
  var outterObject = data[outterKeys[o]];
  var innerKeys = Object.keys(outterObject);
  for(var i = 0; i < innerKeys.length; i++){
    var innerObject = outterObject[innerKeys[i]];
    if (!innerObject){
      data[outterKeys[o]][innerKeys[i]] = true;
    }
  }
}

console.log('es5', data);

/* ES6 */
data = {
    "Presentations": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 5
    },
    "Articles": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 1
    },
    "Blogs": {
        "Instant": true,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": true,
        "ContentTypeId": 61
    },
    "NewsBriefs": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 2
    },
    "SpecialInsights": {
        "Instant": false,
        "Daily": false,
        "WeeklySummary": false,
        "ContentTypeId": 50
    }
};

Object.keys(data).forEach((o) => {
  Object.keys(data[o]).forEach((i) => {
    if (!data[o][i]){
      data[o][i] = true
    }
  })
});
console.log('es6', data);
```